# Node.js: Resolving url with port included

Tags: node.js, url, port, resolve

I want to resolve an url with a port included. 
Concrete example:

```
mainServerURL   ='localhost:8080/';
tempFilesDir    ='/temp';
```

If I call url.resolve on these two variables, I get

```
'localhost:/temp'
```

But I'm actually looking for:

```
'localhost:8080/temp'
```

My code is pretty straightforward, so I'm afraid I must be using url.resolve wrong (due to theoretical errors on my side probably), but I've looked around and can't find another way of doing this.

Of course there's the string-way, but I'm guessing it's avoidable?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need give a more full url like `//localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host of a URL can be [denoted](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) by having the prefix, `//`:

```
> var mainServerURL = '//localhost:8080/';
undefined
> var tempFilesDir  = '/temp';
undefined
> url.resolve(mainServerURL, tempFilesDir)
'//localhost:8080/temp'
```

Without it, `localhost:` is being treated as the protocol rather than the hostname:

```
> url.parse('localhost:8080/', false, true)
{ protocol: 'localhost:',
  host: '8080',
  port: null,
  hostname: '8080',
  ... }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I wouldn't have imagined that made a difference.